# Abbreviation for long python import path

Tags: python, python-import

Given imports like this:

```py
from a.very.long.list.of.packages.aaa.bbb.ccc import abc
from a.very.long.list.of.packages.ddd.eee import de
from a.very.long.list.of.packages.fff import f
from a.very.long.list.of.packages import somepackage
```

is there any way to define aliases for the common part of the module path and reuse it?

I'm imagining something like this:

```py
x = a.very.long.list.of.packages
from x.aaa.bbb.ccc import abc
from x.ddd.eee import de
from x.fff import f
from x import somepackage
```

Comment: Try it if it works

Comment: No, there is no such thing in Python. Generally, we try to keep import names shorter than that.

Comment: As the _author_ of the `a` package however, you can import e.g. `a.very.long.list.of.packages.somepackage` directly in `a` so that the users can just do `from a import somepackage`.

Comment: Is it a third party library, or your own? If it is your own, you might want to expose some of those deeper nested functions in the `__init__.py` file of one of the higher up modules.

Answer (score 2):

Given `x = a.very.long.list.of.packages`, Python will try to resolve all the attributes and fail immediately because no name `a` has been defined. If it already exists, it's unlikely that it has the attribute `very` and the object this attribute points to has the attribute `long` and so on. Anyway, everything to the right of the assignment operator will be evaluated to some object, and it's not possible to import stuff from objects with `from ... import ...`.

You can use dynamic importing with [the built-in `importlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html#module-importlib). It lets you treat strings as paths to modules.